# How to use the QMediaPlayer module to connect to a rtsp stream?

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, video-streaming, qmediaplayer

I'm creating an RTSP stream using FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -probesize 100M -i title="" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 1000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f rtsp -rtsp_transport udp rtsp://...129:8554/stream
```

and trying to connect to it using the Qt module `QMediaPlayer`.

It stuck for many seconds when it read the line
`player->setSource(QUrl("rtsp://....129:8554/stream"));`

and then debug this message:

```
qt.multimedia.ffmpeg.mediadataholder: AVStream duration -9223372036854775808 is invalid. Taking it from the metadata
```

Also, `connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::errorOccurred` print:

`Error: "Invalid argument"`

```
class MediaPlayer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MediaPlayer (QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
    {
        player = new QMediaPlayer;
        player->setSource(QUrl("rtsp://....129:8554/stream"));
        connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::errorOccurred, this, [this](QMediaPlayer::Error error, const QString& errorString)
        {
            qDebug() << "Error:" << errorString;
        });

        videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
        player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);

        videoWidget->show();
        player->play();
    }

private:
    QMediaPlayer* player;
    QVideoWidget* videoWidget;
};
```

Testing the exactly same `streamUrl` on `vlc` does work correctly.
I'm using Qt 6.6, and Win10. ffmpeg 6.0

How I could debug this?

Comment: When you use qt6.50 on windows then see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-111910

Comment: @chehrlic i have updated to qt6.6 still not working.

Answer (score 0):

On the window platform, use the ffmpeg backend, currently Qt does not support playing rtsp video streams.

If you want to support rtsp protocol, you need to compile qt & ffmpeg yourself

--enable-protocol=rtsp

qt 6.5 build config `Env.FFMPEG_DIR_MSVC`
ref https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_6.5_Tools_and_Versions

Comment: Hello, where did you read this information? I could not find a mention to this flag in qt documentation.

Comment: @Daniela I am using Qt 6.5 version. I debugged qt source code, in `qffmpegmediadataholder.cpp` file line 116 `std::optional<MediaDataHolder::ContextError>
MediaDataHolder::recreateAVFormatContext(const QUrl &media, QIODevice *stream) `set a breakpoint to debug, and then check the return value of the `avformat_open_input` function, which shows that the protocol is not supported.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info, i will need to compile with the parameter --enable-protocol=rtsp?

Answer (score 0):

FFMpeg **in Qt** does not support RTSP streams directly.
If you want, you can use GStreamer. By changing the environment variable to gstreamer.
Please see these links:

[QtMultimedia](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-index.html)

[QPut Env](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qputenv)